# Jquery dialog does not center

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a problem trying to center a jquery dialog box. Running this piece of code the dialog box appears in the top left corner in the browser window. I have also tried executing the code using a onclick javascript event so there is no "load" issue. I had a look at some existing questions on "stackoverflow" relating to the same problem but none of them is working for me.

What is wrong? must be something simple it always is.

Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<!--My jQuery library code location -->
<script src="/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script src="/jQuery/js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="/jQuery/js/jquery.ui.dialog.js"></script>
<script src="/jQuery/js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="/jQuery/js/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
<script src="/jQuery/js/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
<script src="/jQuery/js/jquery.ui.resizable.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/jQuery/css/base/jquery.ui.all.css">

<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#span-msg").empty().append("Message");
  $("#div-err-msg").dialog({
    modal: true,
    title: "Testing",
    position: "centre"
  });
});
</script>
<body>

<div id="div-err-msg" style="display:none;">
<span id="span-msg"></span>
</div>

</body>
</head>
</html>
```

You should be able to copy and paste the above code to replicate, just point the jquery src to correct location in your environment

Comment: FYI, your closing `</head>` tag is in the wrong place. It should be before `<body>`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo there, should be: `position: "center"`

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
position: "centre"
```

with

```
position: "center"
```

That should definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your closing of `HEAD` tag is not in correct places.

And in your code, a spelling mistake exist: `"centre"` should be `"center"`.

Try this:

```
 $("#div-err-msg").dialog({
    modal: true,
    title: "Testing",
    position: "center"
  });
```

By Default it's always center of window, you no need to give `position` of UI-Dialog:

```
Default : { my: "center", at: "center", of: window }
```

[Positioning of a UI-dialog](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position)

Try this code (without option-position):

```
$("#div-err-msg").dialog({
    modal: true,
    title: "Testing"
});
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vvjj8/1249/)

Note: Try these changes and let me know it's working or not.

Comment: Not *some*, but that is the only mistake in the javascript code

Answer (score 0):

Your head tag needs to be closed before bode tag.

Then remove all unwanted js reference files from your code. Add below code.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**JQuery:**

```
 $("#LinkId").click(function () {
        $("#div-err-msg").dialog({
            title: "Dialog box",
            height: 300,
            modal: true  
        });
  });
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/8bNRp/1/